# restoring RecyclerView items between activites

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have an activity with multiple recyclerView. Each `recyclerView` loads around 30 `firestore` documents and I feel that loading 30 documents every time the user switches activities is not efficient.

I would like to save the content of my recyclerView when I switch the activity and to load it once I'm back to the first one.

Right now my code (I edited it a bit to show a simplified version) looks like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_discover );

    initUI();

}

private void initUI() {

    LinearLayoutManager layoutManagerPopular = new LinearLayoutManager( this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false );

    rv_Popularitems = findViewById( R.id.rv_Popular );
    rv_Popularitems.setLayoutManager( layoutManagerPopular );

    ShowPopular();

}

private void ShowPopular(){
    HERE I QUERY FIRESTORE AND GET 30 DOCUMNETS AND STORE THEM INTO THE ADAPTER
}

@Override
protected void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    mBundleRecyclerViewState = new Bundle();
    Parcelable listState = rv_Popularitems.getLayoutManager().onSaveInstanceState();
    mBundleRecyclerViewState.putParcelable("KEY", listState);
}

@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    if (mBundleRecyclerViewState != null) {
        Parcelable listState = mBundleRecyclerViewState.getParcelable("KEY");
        rv_Popularitems.getLayoutManager().onRestoreInstanceState(listState);
    }
}
```

From what I read, using the `onPause()` and `onResume()` should do the job. However, I don't understand how it helps if anyway when I return the activity it will go through `onCreate()` which will call `ShowPopular()` = again 30 documents.

Can someone please explain to me how to do it correctly so it will load the 30 documents only the first time the activity is loaded and they will use the values from `onPause()/onResume()`?

Comment: You need to clarify first whether you need a persistent Storage or just a In memory Storage .For  persistent Storage you can use database or you probably won't have to i guess because Firebase does have offline capabilities So explore that. if you need In- memory  persistent then just save the data in a Singelton scope and clear it whenever you need and use it after the first load .

Comment: Cant I just set somehow a condition like: if first time acitivity open then load the items else go to onRestore?

Comment: That's what you do with Singleton. You first check if data exists in Singleton if yes then use it otherwise load it and set it in Singleton .